# how to edit remotely a text file located on a raspberry pi?

Tags: linux, networking, raspberry-pi, http

There is some software running on a raspberry pi, and it would be very useful if a non-tech oriented user could edit one of the (text) configuration file from his mac laptop. The laptop and the pi are on the same network.

Reading the file is simple via http (a http server serves the folder in which the file is located, and the user can visit via his web browser).

But I do not know what would be the simplest way to allow the user to also  edit the file. Setting up some more complex http web server would be a solution, but this seems quite evolved.

Any setup can be done on the pi. Ideally, no setup would be needed on the mac laptop.

Comment: If the non-technical user might make mistakes editing the file, then using the web server would be the safest method: it can check the syntax, that values are valid, and so on, before writing the file to disk. It could even present an interface with just the items that the user can adjust and their possible values in, say, dropdowns.

Answer (score 1):

Does mounting a samba share on the Mac (done once for all) count as a “setup” ?

A solution is to give a ftp/sftp access, and on the Mac side use a ftp client that can “transparently” edit the file on the ftp server. FileZilla can do that. But in my opinion this is not simpler than the samba share. At the end, whatever the solution, the Mac user will have to enter some informations to access the remote server (the Pi).

Edit: I assumed here that the two machine are on the same local network, but you didn't say anything about that. If the Mac accesses the Pi through the internet and without VPN, I don't recommend samba or ftp (sftp is more secure).

Comment: As well as samba, there is also NFS.

Answer (score -2):

You can make use of open source applications like WinSCP. Next, start an SFTP session. After that, you can locate the file you wish to modify in your server's filesystem and browse there. You can use the right click menu to open the file in your Windows environment in your preferred editor.

Comment: WinSCP a little chance to run on a *"Mac laptop"*!